# errors when trying to initialize vm_args

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

When i initialize `JDK1_1InitArgs` using `JDK1_1InitArgs vm_args` compiler gives me errors.
I need this variable initialized to use the function `JNI_CreateJavaVM`.

```
            JavaVM *jvm;
            JNIEnv *env;
            jmethodID mid;
            JDK1_1InitArgs vm_args; // Line 47
            vm_args.version = 0x00010001; // Line 48
            JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&vm_args);
            vm_args.classpath = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/lib;.;";

            JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, &env, &vm_args);
            env = (*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm,&env,NULL);
            jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,Obj);
            mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,cls,"callBack","(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
            (*env)->CallVoidMethodA(env,Obj,mid,(*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"1B"));
```

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html)

*Errors :*

[image]

Why do i get these errors ? How can i get rid of them ?

Comment: That struct may have been removed from the header file.  See [this bug report here.](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5031222)

Comment: @JoeFish what is the alternative ?

Comment: I don't know, which is why I didn't post that as an answer.  I'm sure some more Google searching would yield the solution though.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/jni-12.html#JNI_CreateJavaVM

Comment: Not in jni.h in either JDK 1.6 or 1.7. Are you really writing JNI for a 1.1 JVM?

Comment: @EJP no. I read a book that was too old to mention this ! the pdf from sun

Answer (score 1):

JNI 1.1 is no longer supported. See a comment from HotSpot's `jvm.h`, right before the definition of `struct JDK1_1InitArgs`:

> This structure is used by the launcher to get the default thread
>   stack size from the VM using JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs() with a
>   version of 1.1.  As it is not supported otherwise, it has been removed
>   from jni.h

*Source: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.h, line 1673*

It appears to be impossible to create a JVM versioned 1.1 in JDK 7 -- which means that you might want to use a later version such as 1.2, or use an older JDK.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, you can probably simply replace it with the struct

```
JavaVMInitArgs
```

However, make sure to also initialize the version member correctly, e.g.

```
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
```